# Maximum number of queries by a single Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is there any limitations on the number of queries that a single Facebook app can make?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the query and the access_token used.  There are no documented limits and even if there were, it'd likely change depending on Facebook's need.

Essentially you can make as many requests as you want until you get a `request limit reached` error message.

Edit:
Some methods will limit the number of queries per user.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i build an app  and promise my customers  a working app depending on the queries if facebook can suddenly shut me down?

Comment: The request limit is the least of your problems if that's a concern.  Facebook will shut down applications for "policy violations" and not bother telling you what the issue is or giving you a chance to appeal it.  Basically, make sure your customers know what they're getting in to and that you have no control over what Facebook does.